# Best Binary reader for C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, binary, 3dsmax

I've looking through the internet the best way to read binary files, and they all lead to ifstream or istream.

I'm not saying that they are bad, but i can't manage to get along with. much, since i can only manage to read numbers.

I'm looking for some equivalent of C#'s BinaryReader in C++, and even if it's harder, i would like to find anywhere some guidelines to start with, i can only find guides of people reading a full file buffer and not much else

I tried using the System::IO binary reader from C# but since i use mutex i can't go to that option.

Here is how i am reading the stuff.

```
std::ifstream f(filename, std::ios::binary); //Open the file

f.read((char*)&header, sizeof(4)); //ReadInt32

SCNObject obj(f);
```

The constructor:

```
SCNObject::SCNObject(std::ifstream& f)
{
    f.read((char*)&ID, sizeof(4));
    name = (ReadString(f));
    parentName = (ReadString(f));
}
```

My ReadString function:

```
std::string ReadNTString(std::ifstream& file)
{
    char ch = 0;
    std::string str = "";
    while (ch != '\0')
    {
        ch = file.get();
        str += ch;
    }
    return str;
}
```

At this point i thought i was going to get what i was looking for, but i just got numbers on the strings.
Log:

```
Name: 1288880
Parent Name: 1288880
```

And they do not share the same name at all, so i'm pretty confused right now, and i don't want to imagine how i am going to make it when i try to read floats.

i'm aware this is not the way to do it and i bet there is a better way of doing it, but i just can't find it on the internet, is the same tutorial over and over and i don't get how to do it, or i just don't do it right, learning c++ alone is hard...

if someone can give me some guidances on how to learn to parse basic data such as floats, null-terminated strings, and in case there is a better way read ints to be so, i would really appreciate it, i'm so lost and i don't know what to do.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Fyi, `sizeof(4)` ? Did you intend this to read a guaranteed 4 bytes, or was the integral constant `4` being used to somehow send `sizeof(int)` (which is what it is actually doing) ?

Comment: The usual pattern is `f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&header), sizeof header);`. The ugly syntax makes you twitch by design, as this isn't necessarily portable. I like to define a `read` function that SFINAEs with `std::is_trivial` (or `std::is_trivially_copyable` if your library supports it) to make sure I don't use it for non-trivial classes.

Comment: The 4 was to make sure that i was reading 4 bytes, but i never thought of using size of int instead, thanks :P

And yeah, my library supports it, i can check it out and use it!

Comment: @SeyrenWindsor Judging by how you responded, I don't think you understood my comment.  `sizeof(4)` **is** `sizeof(int)`, as `4` is just that; an `int`. If you wanted to read *exactly* **4** octets then that is what you pass: **4**. There is no `sizeof` in that case. And if this is a fixed-format file potentially write and read by multiple platforms, `sizeof(int)` is *not* what you should be using regardless.

Comment: Oh, i got it wrong then, sorry, i understood it wrong, then the way i'm doing it is correct, as you said, this is a fixed format file that is going to be readed in 3D engines, i already coded it in C# but i'm interested in learning this language + 3ds max only uses C++ in their plugins.

Comment: PS: For some reason fread crashes the whole thing after compiling, even fopen, so i have to scratch that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boost's serialization library

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

It supports binary serialization of c++ primitives and STL containers and provides a framework to extend serialization to your own types. (But keep in mind it's not portable across different machine architectures)

Here's what serialization would look like for simple strings and floats.

```
//writer.cpp
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>                                                       
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>                                                    
#include <fstream>                                                                              

int main() {                                                                                    
  std::ofstream out("mydata.bin");                                                              
  boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarchive(out);                                                
  std::string s = "abc";                                                                        
  float x = 123.0f;                                                                             
  oarchive << s << x;                                                                           
  return 0;                                                                                     
} 

//reader.cpp
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>                                                       
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>                                                    
#include <fstream>                                                                              

int main() {                                                                                    
  std::ifstream in("mydata.bin");                                                               
  boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarchive(in);                                                 
  std::string s;                                                                                
  float x;                                                                                      
  iarchive >> s >> x;                                                                           
  std::cout << s << x << '\n';                                                                  
  return 0;                                                                                     
}
```

Comment: The way i'm reading the code seems to by just what i need for the floats and strings!, i'm going to try it and i'll let you know!

Comment: I got a lot of erros and exceptions after putting it in, specially syntax may be my fault, i can't continue on this today, i'll let you tomorrow, but seems like this may be the thing i'm looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::getline` to read in `std::string`.  You can specify an end of string character or use the default newline.

The best method for reading from files is to read in large blocks, then manipulate these blocks from memory.  This reduces the number of requests to the input stream.